# jQuery: Handle fallback for failed AJAX Request

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, callback, wait

Can jQuery provide a fallback for failed AJAX calls? This is my try:

```
function update() {
    var requestOK = false;

    $.getJSON(url, function(){
        alert('request successful');
        requestOK = true;
    });

    if (!requestOK) {
        alert('request failed');
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, even if the callback function of the $.getJSON() method is called, i get the message 'request failed', before the callback function has the opportunity to set the requestOK variable. I think it's because the code runs in parallel. Is there a way to handle such situations? I thought about chaining or some way of waiting for the AJAX request, including its callback function. But how? Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You will need to either use the lower level [$.ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options) call, or the [ajaxError](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/ajaxError#callback) function. Here it is with the $.ajax method:

```
function update() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: url,
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data, textStatus ){
       alert('request successful');
    },
    fail: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
       alert('request failed');
    }
  });
}
```

**EDIT** I added a `timeout` to the `$.ajax` call and set it to five seconds.

Comment: that's already great! but it doesn't seem to work, if the internet connection is down :(. that's quite important, because i'm developing a dashboard widget for osx and want to display some kind of message, saying that a request was not possible. any other tips?

Comment: @Patrick, I updated my answer to include the `timeout` parameter. It should call the error function after 5 seconds if the internet connection is down.

Comment: sorry for all the double question trouble and so on! i opened a new question because i thought, that my original question was basically answered and it would be more appropriate to move it to a new one. didn't know that the answer to my second question had so much to do with my first one ;) nevertheless, i cheered to soon. still doesn't fall back to the error function, even if i set the timeout parameter to 1, which would be absolutely unrealistic. is it possible that the timeout parameter is overridden by something else?

Comment: No worries, I was being to sensitive. Let me look into it more. Since you do have the other question now, I will post my findings over there :)

Comment: Works for me, exactly when the server is down or the session is stale.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 14):

Dougs answer is correct, but you actually can use `$.getJSON` and catch errors (not having to use `$.ajax`). Just chain the `getJSON` call with a call to the `fail` function:

```
$.getJSON('/foo/bar.json')
    .done(function() { alert('request successful'); })
    .fail(function() { alert('request failed'); });
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NLDYf/5/

This behavior is part of the jQuery.Deferred interface.
Basically it allows you to attach events to an asynchronous action *after* you call that action, which means you don't have to pass the event function to the action.

Read more about jQuery.Deferred here: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: `.error()` is deprecated as of jQuery v1.8 and you should use `.fail()`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's built in to jQuery.  See the docs at [jquery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax).

ajaxError may be what you want.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to this approach because you can return the promise and use .then(successFunction, failFunction); anywhere you need to.

```
var promise = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: url,
    timeout: 5000
  }).then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
    alert('request successful');
  }, function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
    alert('request failed');
});

//also access the success and fail using variable
promise.then(successFunction, failFunction);
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that what you are looking for is error option for the jquery [ajax object](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options)

getJSON is a wrapper to the `$.ajax` object, but it doesn't provide you with access to the error option.

EDIT:
dcneiner has given a good example of the code you would need to use. (Even before I could post my reply)

Comment: Wrong about getJSON not give access to errors. You can access the error option by form of chaining the getJSON call. See @Lasse Dahl Ebert's answer.

Comment: @Fydo - this answer actually *predates* jQuery's Deferred by over a year ;-)  At the time, there was now way to get access to the error, you had to drop down to the `$.ajax` method.