# Javascript Ajax call another page php, and show aleft if another page php is show ERROR

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

Good morning guys.

I try to change a php platform with javascript and ajax, it is a new project and I have little knowledge of javascript.

And got that an html form is received by another php subpage by ajax, everything works correctly. But I have no idea, how can I do that in the case of the php subpage, it says Correct teach Alert ok, and if it says Error I put another alert Error on the web, and in this way I can see if everything is ok or something not to it worked

The php subpage, just show that Corect, Error.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="javascript:cancelClicked(nombre.value, menu.value)">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class="card-title">Datos del nuevo <?php echo $menu; ?></h4>

                                        <input type="hidden" readonly class="form-control" id="empresa" name="empresa" placeholder="<?php echo $empresa;?>" value="<?php echo $empresa;?>">

                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label for="nif" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">Nombre</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <input type="text" name='nombre' autofocus class="form-control" id="nombre" placeholder="<?php echo $menu;?> Nombre" value="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                        <input type="hidden" name='menu' readonly class="form-control" id="menu" placeholder="<?php echo $menu;?>" value="<?php echo $menu;?>">

                                        <input type="hidden" name='submenu' readonly class="form-control" id="submenu" placeholder="<?php echo $submenu;?>" value="<?php echo $submenu;?>">

                            </div>
                            <div class="border-top">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <script language="javascript">
    function cancelClicked(txt,txt2) {
        // function below will run clear.php?h=michael
        //var txt3 = txt ;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "agregar-nuevo.php?empresa=Cristaleria+Iberica+S.A.&nombre=" + txt + "&menu=" + txt2 + "&submenu=Listado" ,
            data: { id: "nombre" },
            success : function() { 

                // here is the code that will run on client side after running clear.php on server

                // function below reloads current page
               // alert(<?php $string = $txt3; echo $string;?>);
                 alert(txt + " Agregado con exito en " + txt2);
                    location.reload();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

AND the php subpage

```
    <?php
// Get values from form 

$producto=$_GET['nombre'];
$menu=$_GET['menu'];
$submenu=$_GET['submenu'];

$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 hours"));
$date2 = date("H:i:s", strtotime("+1 hours"));

     $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+1 hours"));                                   
/// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `producto` WHERE empresa = '$empresa' AND menu = '$menu' AND producto= '$producto' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);                        
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {



    $id = $row["id"];   
if (!empty($row["id"]))  {
echo 'ERROR';
}else{
    $tbl_name="producto"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
$con132=mysqli_connect("$servername", "$username", "$password","$dbname")or         die("cannot connect server "); 



// Insert data into mysql 
$sql132="INSERT INTO `producto` (`id`, `empresa`, `producto`, `menu`, `fecha`, `hora`, `usuario`) VALUES (NULL, '$empresa', '$producto', '$menu', '$date', '$date2', '$miusuario');";
$result132=mysqli_query($con132,$sql132);

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful". 
if($result132){



}

else {

}
}


    }
} else {
    $tbl_name="producto"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
$con132=mysqli_connect("$servername", "$username", "$password","$dbname")or         die("cannot connect server "); 



// Insert data into mysql 
$sql132="INSERT INTO `producto` (`id`, `empresa`, `producto`, `menu`, `fecha`, `hora`, `usuario`) VALUES (NULL, '$empresa', '$producto', '$menu', '$date', '$date2', '$miusuario');";
$result132=mysqli_query($con132,$sql132);

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful". 
if($result132){
//echo "Correcto <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=https://www.appnet.dev/empleado/listado.php?menu=". $menu ."&submenu=". $submenu ."' />";
echo "Correcto";

}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
}

?>
```

Comment: > This post looks duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844370/jquery-handle-fallback-for-failed-ajax-request

Comment: It is not the same, I am interested that, error or correct, put them on alert, not if the page exists, because the page exists is internal. I want you to give me these messages if subpage php has problems putting the data in mysql or if everything has gotten right.